# PHP explode string on if

Tags: php, xml

My code that reads an XML file is as follows:

```
<?php
    if ( $dance['block'] == $dance['user']['ip'] ) : ?>
<?php e(o("N/A")) ?>
```

Right now, that `if()` statement is reading the entire XML file as one string.  So next I used:

```
$array6 = explode(",", $this->block);
$result['block']   = (string) $array6;
```

This was supposed to explode each `$dance['user']['ip']`, but I'm not sure why it's not working.

Any ideas, fixes, or tips?

Comment: Can you give an example of the string?

Comment: is `$this->block` set to anything?  Should your previous statement be `$this->block = e(o("N/A"));`  Either way you should have a semicolon at the end of that statement.

Comment: Are you looking to convert a string like this `a,b,c,d,e` to this `abcde`?

Comment: The string in xml is
<blocked>1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,3.3.3.3</blocked>

$this->block is set to something.

Answer (score 0):

Casting an array to a string will unhelpfully give you the string "Array" as well as throw a nifty warning. I'm not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish there.

For your test to see if a user's ip is in the block list you should do the following:

```
$blockList = explode(",", $blockedIpString);
if (in_array($dance['user']['ip'], $blockList)){
     // user is blocked
} else { 
     // user is not blocked
}
```